# Save views in cache

Tags: iphone, ipad, caching, xcode4.5

My project is `webservice oriented`.So when iphone goes offline then data is not loaded and it shows `empty views(combination of textfields,tableviews,webviews)`.For this I came across caching concept.But everything is related to images.What I need is executing the services and `displaying the data in webviews,tableviews`.
How can I do it ?

Any idea's/suggestion's would be appreciable...

Answer (score 0):

Core data allow you to syns with direct web service, You can also use sqlite if data is not too large.  For images save all the image in directory and check if it already exist in DB then do not download. Please refer below link.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2

[How to sync CoreData and a REST web service asynchronously and the same time properly propagate any REST errors into the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077444/how-to-sync-coredata-and-a-rest-web-service-asynchronously-and-the-same-time-pro)

AFIncrementalStore works fine with a simple REST API.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore

you can also use  restkit for same.
http://restkit.org/

Comment: Actually in my project all the data will be saved in database and by using webservices Im loading that data .So when it comes to CoderData it is like again saving to database.Can u tell me to save the data in some files or anything of such way without again storing in database ?But one exception is data may vary(large or small).