# Get changed objects in NSManagedObjectContext before saving?

Tags: rest, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to save changes on backend also, so I want to subclass NSManagedContext, override save method and loop al the changed object and call the appropriate RESTFull service. But how can I get the changed / inserted objects?

UPDATE:

I found that with setIncludesPendingChanges I can get the changed objects, but I still need to set the entity name for NSFetchRequest. But I want to fetch all different type of entites. How?

Comment: I found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235498/coredata-fetching-an-object-from-an-unsaved-context

Comment: Please write that as an answer, then accept it, so that your question doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, answer above is not complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found here a more appropriate solution based on NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification: [How to sync CoreData and a REST web service asynchronously and the same time properly propagate any REST errors into the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077444/how-to-sync-coredata-and-a-rest-web-service-asynchronously-and-the-same-time-pro)